# Kohana param() don't work

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I'm using Kohana 3. Does anyone knows why param('controller') result is NULL.

Routing:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'page',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

URL: `http://localhost/application/page/index/1`

Params calls:

```
$param = Request::instance()->param('controller');
echo Kohana::debug($param); //results: NULL
$param = Request::instance()->param('action');
echo Kohana::debug($param); //results: NULL
$param = Request::instance()->param('id');
echo Kohana::debug($param); //results: 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look up in reqeuest.php on line 622:

```
// These are accessible as public vars and can be overloaded
unset($params['controller'], $params['action'], $params['directory']);

// Params cannot be changed once matched
$this->_params = $params;
```

that's why line 695 can't return `controller`:

```
public function param($key = NULL, $default = NULL)
{
    return $this->_params[$key];
}
```

this is how you get the controller `$controller = Request::instance()->controller;` or `$controller = $this->request->controller;` if you inside a controller

Comment: Has this changed in Kohana 3.1? :-(

Comment: I've answered my question below. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For everybody using Kohana 3.1 access the name of the current controller and action like this within a controller:

`$this->request->controller()`

`$this->request->action()`

Or if you're not in a controller, you can always access the methods of the current request like this: `Request::current()->controller()`

See `system/classes/kohana/request.php` for more methods you can access similarly.